# Elegant and efficient way to store default values at compile time?

Tags: c++, time, parameters, compilation, default

Edit: I understand now what's happening. I was getting the idea that the class and its instantiation were being duplicated in RAM from the fact that when I added one character (one byte) to one of the labels (changing "White Oyster Incubation" to "White Oyster IncubationX"), the Arduino IDE told me that 2 more bytes were being used by the dynamic memory, so I was assuming that one was for the class, and another for the instatiation.

Turns out that for some reason strings from String.h seem to allocate 2 bytes at a time, so the size of a one character string is 2, two character string is 2, three character string is 3, and so forth. The size grows in even numbers.

Of course, now I realize that the class is being stored in the Arduino PROGMEM (EPROM), and the instantiation is in RAM, so the data is not really being duplicating in RAM.

Original question follows:
I'm making a program for an Arduino (atmega328), in which a mushroom greenhouse is to be controlled. There should exist several profiles for temperature and humidity parameters, for different stages in the mushroom development.
I want to have these profiles saved at compile time, and then have the Arduino change between profiles, to act accordingly.
I thought of this:

```
class GrowingProfile
{
private:
int idealTemp; 

int idealHumi;

String label;

public:
GrowingProfile(int idealTemp,int idealHumi, String label)
{
    this->idealTemp = idealTemp;
    this->idealHumi = idealHumi;
    this->label = label;
};
//general methods
};

    class mushroomSpecies1Profiles
{
public:
 GrowingProfile incubationProfile;
 GrowingProfile fruitingProfile;

 WhiteOysterGrowingProfiles():
     incubationProfile (100, 95, "White Oyster Incubation"),
     fruitingProfile (20, 4, "White Oyster Fruiting"){}

};
```

And then, in the main code, have an instance of mushroomSpecies1Profiles pass its members as arguments to the methods that determine if the envioronment conditions (set in the profiles) are good or not.

However, this is, in my view, bloated, as effectively the data is duplicated, in the class definition, and then in the instantiation. And given that the microcontroller in question only has 2K of memory...
What would be a good way to not have the data duplicated in the final executable? As if it was a static class in C#?

Comment: I do not see anything duplicated here.

Comment: Is the number of profiles fixed at compile time? And if so, can you put the names into an enum? If so, you could use a templated class.

Comment: You should not abuse a class for things belonging into a namespace.

Comment: You can remove the `this->` syntax by choosing different names between member variables and method parameters.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Or even better: Use the member initializer list (and optionally rename the parameters).

Comment: @DieterLücking I'd appreciate if you'd elaborate on that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your class GrowingProfile is truly constant and unchanging, I would recommend something along these lines:

```
static const GrowingProfile incubationProfile (100, 95, "White Oyster Incubation");
static const GrowingProfile fruitingProfile (20, 4, "White Oyster Fruiting");
```

Comment: That indeed works for avoiding duplicating the data for any instances of the class

Answer (score 1):

String literals are part of the program, if defined (in any way) in the program. To avoid memory consumption of these literals, you can put these in a separate file, taking the cost of mapping the literals (e.g.: via an integer key) while accessing that file.

However, if the the program and file system are located in the same limited EPROM, you are doomed. You have to be be brief as possible.

Comment: That would be a good in other architecture. But indeed the Arduino only has one EPROM